# how to see all log data in loki?

Tags: python, logging, grafana, grafana-loki

i'm using Loki as log management system , and i send log like this :

```
        logger = logging.getLogger("loki")
        logger.info(
        "download_file",
        extra={"tags": {"module": "download_file", "step": 1, "started_time": time.time()},
               "data": {"user": request.user.pk, "symbols": symbols, 'time_frame': time_frame, "from_date": from_date,
                        "to_date": to_date,
                        "file_id":action.id,
                        "unique_id" : unique_id}
               },
    )
```

in Grafana dashboard i can see only "module, step, started_time" . i cannot see the 'data' section in dashboard , how i can see them ? or is my log format true and work in Loki or i have to send all metrics in 'tags' section ?

Answer (score 0):

In which dashboard you'd like to see your data?

You can see all your log messages using [Grafana Explore](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/explore/)

You don't need your data inside the `tags`. The tags are used as Loki labels. Using `step` and `timestamp` as labels will generate a label cardinality explosion and that would have an impact on performance. [You can read more on labels here](https://grafana.com/blog/2020/08/27/the-concise-guide-to-labels-in-loki/).

Answer (score 0):

If you have not solved your problem yet, [this](https://medium.com/geekculture/pushing-logs-to-loki-without-using-promtail-fc31dfdde3c6) article solves the problem.

In short, you need to set the default level to a lower level, for example to DEBUG. This is done with `logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)`